# Cannot see front-end or login to back-end of WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a site for my client and the site is live and right now it is not viewable. When I try to login to a WordPress back-end, I can't see anything.

Here is the site: http://www.theselfloveproject.net/
Here is the back-end login: http://www.theselfloveproject.net/wp-admin/

What I was doing before it blanked out, was going into the editor (html editor) for one of my plugins. I updated it and then that's when it went blank. As if I messed up something with the overall coding of the site. I'm not sure what I did.

Answer (score 0):

please set 
`define('WP_DEBUG', true);` at `wp-config.php` file and you will see where is issue.

Comment: How do I do that? I can't see anything at all and can't get to my back-end at all

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the update you've made is preventing access. Try disabling or removing the plugin that you edited using FileZilla (or some equivalent) to check whether you can access the login screen again.

Comment: How do I do that? This is for an internship and right now I'm being very unprofessional, I'm really worried. Because all I really know is that her site is with bluehost, and I don't know her server login credentials etc, to use filezilla

Comment: If you can gain access to the host there should be a file manager section where you can access the wordpress plugins, but again you're going to need login credentials.

Comment: Ok, so I know what to ask her, all I need is everything to enter in the normal site manager form in filezilla? From there what do I do?

Comment: Is there any possible work around whatsoever? Really not wanting to ask her for her credentials, let alone have her know this happened at all...

Comment: Once you gain access through Filezilla, you need to navigate to the "wp-content/plugins" folder. The plugin you modified should be within that directory. You can then save a copy to your desktop and delete the one located on the website. This post on WPBeginner could be helpful: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-manually-update-wordpress-using-ftp/

Comment: I'm not aware of any other way -- sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You got a php-error somewhere, and without access to the FTP you will not be able to solve it. So just get the information from the client, don't worry it happens to all of us sometimes, no need to feel ashamed.

Once you got the credentials and FTP-access, find the wp-config.php in the root and set define('WP_DEBUG', true); reload the page and you should see what error message you get and in which file at what line.

Sounds like you updated a plugin and something went wrong.

Basically, always have FTP-credentials for live sites you are responsible for. You don't know when you will need it.